# Is my server-side content safe?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, proxy

I am getting this in my apache error_log and I am using AWS

```
[Mon Oct 31 08:24:47.120132 2016] [:error] [pid 8216] [client 95.213.177.126:34294] script '/var/www/html/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
```

I wanted to know what does that mean.

Comment: Based on the information you've provided there is **nothing** to suggest that your site may have been compromised. Nor is there anything to suggest your site has **not** been compromised. Nor can we understand the extent of the gap in your knowledge.

Comment: I just saw it on my apache logs, so I asked! Please provide me any information if you have.

Comment: It means that something via proxyradar.com tried to access this script on your side and it was not found. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a request was made for `/var/www/html/azenv.php`, which was not found. That's a standard 404 error, when a request has been made for a non-existent file.

As to WHY the request was made, that's for the sender to determine.

See [Apache access log full of unauthorized and suspicious requests, how to take action](https://serverfault.com/questions/753493/apache-access-log-full-of-unauthorized-and-suspicious-requests-how-to-take-acti), which suggests that it is *automated scripts looking for vulnerabilities of unpatched servers*.

The fact that the file was **not** found should give you some comfort, because that's one vulnerability to which you were not vulnerable.

Comment: It also means you should examine your logs for successful requests from that host.